# Custom timestamp format

Tags: php, html, forms

Sorry if this exists, I just can't find it anywhere.

I'm using `$timestamp =date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');` to save `Sunday 16th of June 2019 09:59:40 PM`

How would I go about getting it to output `DD/MM/YYYY 00:00` with 24hr format rather than the AM/PM taking up space.

There's some with `MM/DD/YYYY` but I don't know how to modify it.

Any pointers would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you need to know can be found in the manual:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

```
d // days in numbers 01-31
m // months in number 01 - 12
Y // years in 4 digits
H // hours in numbers 00.00 - 23.00
i // minutes in numbers
```

The timestamp would look like this:

```
$timestamp =date('d/m/Y H:i');
```

Answer (score 1):

The format you need is:

```
date('d/m/Y H:i:s');
```

date function accept a string parameter and you can compose it as you need using the formatting options that you can find here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

Hours in 24 hours format is `H`.

```
date('d/m/Y H:i')
```

For more options check the Manual, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: That's doesn't work, except for the `H:i` section. The answer from Thorsten Wolske works.